# Android back-button causes crash?

Tags: android, crash, android-camera

I have a problem where my app keeps crashing once Im in the app and press the "back-button" on my phone and then enters the app again.. I guess im handeling some kind of state or something wrong:

```
package com.animeus;

import com.animeus.Factories.CameraDialogsFactory;
import com.animeus.Factories.CameraFactory;
import com.animeus.Services.CameraService;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.hardware.Camera;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;

public class LightBulbActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    Camera c;

    //Application starts here
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        loadComponentsToUse();
        setComponentEvents();

        if (c == null)
            CameraDialogsFactory.GetNoCameraFoundDialog(this).show();
        else
            setComponentEvents();
    }

    //Sets all the components events
    private void setComponentEvents() {
        View v = (View)findViewById(R.id.LightBulbView);
        v.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                triggerLightEvent(event.getAction());
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    //Turns the led on or off
    private void triggerLightEvent(int currentevent) {
        if (currentevent == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
            CameraService.turnLedLightOn(c);
        else if (currentevent == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            CameraService.turnLedLightOff(c);
        }
    }

    //Loads the "global" components we are supposed to use
    private void loadComponentsToUse() {
        c = CameraFactory.getCamera();
    }

    //Called once the activity ain't visible for the user anymore
    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }


    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
    }
}
```

any ideas?
I also tried to release the camera on "onPause" and "onStop" and then recreate the camera "onResume" but that cause the app to crash aswell...

and yeah I know.. this aint the full code.. but if you need more of the code, then let me know

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Not entirely sure, but I've seen people disposing their camerase in the onPause event. It's up to you figuring out how android messes around with undisposed stuff :p

Comment: Do you have a stacktrace or some logs?

Answer (score 3):

What kind of action do you want to take place when the user hits the back button? In my apps if the user is in the main activity and not deep in the activity stack I override the backbutton to prompt the user with an `AlertDialog` that asks them if they would like to exit the app and then if they press yes I use `System.exit()` after I clean house so to speak with a method I create to kill and nullify everything first.

You can override the back button like so:

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    super.onBackPressed();
    cleanHouse();
    System.exit(0);     
}
```

You could also put this in your `onPause()`:

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    try{
        cam.camera.release();
    }catch(NullPointerException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        try{
            cam.camera.unlock();
        }catch(NullPointerException f){
            f.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: well I dont think the actuall problem is the action of the back-button
More like when the user "reopens" the app.. thats when the crash happens..

Comment: but Im thinking if you use the system.exit() it should kill the state of the app like it hasnt been started so all views would be set to go through oncreate again.....that would help with the problem you have with the camera but it would keep the crash from happening in onresume. Ill add a little example of what i use in onPause to free up the camera and catch errors.

Comment: If those arent working for you then you should add a logcat dump to the question so we can see the error stack